# extract key as well as value from a array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have searched this question on google but doesnt find any suitable solution.

Suppose i have an array of objects as below --

```
 "points":[{"pt":"Point-1","value":"Java, j2ee developer"},{"pt":"Point-2","value":"Experienced in Core Java, Spring, Hibernate, JPA, Big Data, SOA, BPEL"}]
```

Now from above array i want to extract key as wellas values for a specific pair so that my result will look as below --

```
 [{"value":"Java, j2ee developer"},{"value":"Experienced in Core Java, Spring, Hibernate, JPA, Big Data, SOA, BPEL"}]
```

I know this can be done using manual looping. But i dont wanna loop through. Is it possible to get result in one go using lodash or some other api ?

Comment: `i want to extract key as wellas values for a specific pair` what do you mean by specific pair? On what condition do you want to filter the items of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your array:

```
var points = [
    { 'pt': 'Point-1', 'value': 'Java, j2ee developer' },
    { 'pt': 'Point-2', 'value': 'Experienced in ...' }
];

var result = points.map(function(p) {
    return { value: p.value };
});
```

Comment: Hi Its returning the desired value but it is not returning in the JSON format. Instead of
     [{"value":"Java, j2ee developer"},{"value":"Experienced in Core Java, Spring, Hibernate, JPA, Big Data, SOA, BPEL"}]
It is returning as
     [ { value: 'Java, j2ee developer' },  { value: 'Experienced in Core Java, Spring, Hibernate, JPA, Big Data, SOA, BPEL' } ]
Due to this it is not assignable to an other object as is.

Comment: @rraghuva it returns javascript object, if you want string as result you can stringify it e.g.: `JSON.stringify(result)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest version of Javascript you can also make use of destructuring in your call to map, allowing you to extract the properties you care about in an elegant way.

```
points.map(({ value }) => ({ value }));
```

The arrow function takes a `point` object as an argument and uses `{ value }` to destructure the `point.value` property into a variable called `value`.

Then it returns a shorthand object literal which uses `value` as both the key and the value.

When compiled with Babel, we get:

```
points.map(function (_ref) {
  var value = _ref.value;
  return { value: value };
});
```

Comment: I tested it in console. It is printing `[undefined, undefined]`

Comment: @madox2 how you guys are understanding that new feature destructuring.  It is difficult for me to understand. :\